# How to manually resolve an address in WireShark?

Tags: networking, dns, wireshark

There is an address in the capture window that i want to manually resolve:

[image: image description]

So i right-click the address, click **Manually Resolve Address**, and enter a **Name** for the address:

[image: image description]

When i click **OK**, WireShark does *something*:

[image: image description]

And when it comes back, WireShark has done nothing:

[image: image description]

What am i doing wrong?

## Bonus Reading

- https://ask.wireshark.org/question/21717/manually-configuring-service-port-names-on-windows/
- https://ask.wireshark.org/question/6172/edit-resolved-names/
- https://osqa-ask.wireshark.org/questions/9173/can-i-save-manual-address-resolutions/
- https://osqa-ask.wireshark.org/questions/23823/manually-resolve-hostnames-not-working/
- https://bugs.wireshark.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=9064
- https://ask.wireshark.org/question/25386/how-to-manually-resolve-an-address/

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: https://www.wireshark.org/#download The Widows version